# How to make forward declaration of a struct in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

Imagine this highly contrived example:  (Note this is for Arduino-flavored C, not ANSI C):

```
typedef struct _node {
  int value;
  struct _node *next;
} node;
```

Using this, I can construct a linked list of two nodes by building the list "backwards":

```
node nodeB = { 2, (node *)0 };  // end of list
node nodeA = { 1, &nodeB };     // A.next => B
```

But instead, what if I'd like to make a circularly linked list?  This won't work:

```
node nodeA = { 1, &nodeB };
node nodeB = { 2, &nodeA };
```

since nodeB is not declared at the time that nodeA wants to reference it.

I could build the linked list at run time (dynamically allocate the nodes, then set up the `next` links).  But is there a way to get a valid forward declaration at compile time?

Comment: Would an ordinary forward reference work? Try sticking "extern node nodeB;" up front.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Gosh -- yes that works.  I didn't try that because the language reference page (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) doesn't mention `extern` as a language construct.  I invite you to turn your comment into an answer... :)

Comment: In C (but not C++) you can write `node nodeB;` as forward declaration

Comment: Why do you require the circularly linked list to be set up at compile time?   A simple assignment of the form `nodeA.next = &nodeB` (after `nodeA` and `nodeB` are both defined) isn't exactly a large run time overhead.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is a contrived example.  My actual use case involves stringing together much more complicated structures, and given the restrictions of the Arduino, I'd like to avoid dynamic allocation when possible.

Comment: `I didn't try that because the language reference page (arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) doesn't mention extern as a language construct.` - it is important to be aware that the "Arduino language" is in fact C++ with a little pre-processing done so you don't have to make your own function prototypes (sometimes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a fairly ordinary situation where a forward declaration will work:

```
extern node nodeB;
node nodeA = { 1, &nodeB };
node nodeB = { 2, &nodeA };
```

Comment: What if they want internal linkage for both

Comment: Maybe anonymous namespace, perhaps: `class node { public: int x; };

namespace {

   extern node nodeb;
};


namespace {

   node nodeb;
};`